# How to speed up MongoDB Inserts/sec?

Tags: perl, mongodb

I'm trying to maximize inserts per second. I currently get around 20k inserts/sec. My performance is actually degrading the more threads and CPU I use (I have 16 cores available). 2 threads currently do more per sec than 16 threads on a 16 core dual processor machine. Any ideas on what the problem is? Is it because I'm using only one mongod? Is it indexing that could be slowing things down? Do I need to use sharding? I wonder if there's a way to shard, but also keep the database capped...

**Constraints**: must handle around 300k inserts/sec, must be self-limiting(capped), must be query-able relatively quickly

**Problem Space**: must handle call records for a major cellphone company (around 300k inserts/sec) and make those call records query-able for as long as possible (a week, for instance)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

use MongoDB;
use Time::HiRes;

my $conn = MongoDB::Connection->new;

my $db = $conn->tutorial;

my $users = $db->users;

my $cmd = Tie::IxHash->new(
    "create"    => "users",
    "capped"    => "boolean::true",
    "max"       => 10000000,
    );

$db->run_command($cmd);

my $idx = Tie::IxHash->new(
    "background"=> "boolean::true",
);
$users->ensure_index($idx);


my $myhash =
    {
        "name"  => "James",
        "age"   => 31,
        #    "likes" => [qw/Danielle biking food games/]
    };

my $j : shared = 0;

my $numthread = 2;  # how many threads to run

my @array;
for (1..100000) {
    push (@array, $myhash);
    $j++;
}

sub thInsert {
    #my @ids = $users->batch_insert(\@array);
    #$users->bulk_insert(\@array);
    $users->batch_insert(\@array);
}

my @threads;

my $timestart = Time::HiRes::time();
push @threads, threads->new(\&thInsert) for 1..$numthread;
$_->join foreach @threads; # wait for all threads to finish
print (($j*$numthread) . "\n");
my $timeend = Time::HiRes::time();

print( (($j*$numthread)/($timeend - $timestart)) . "\n");

$users->drop();
$db->drop();
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Writes to MongoDB currently aquire a global write lock, although [collection level locking](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1240) is hopefully coming soon.  By using more threads you're likely introducing more concurrency problems as the threads block eachother while they wait for the lock to be released.

Indexes will also slow you down, to get the best insert performance it's ideal to add them after you've loaded your data, however this isn't always possible, for example if you're using a unique index.

To really maximise write performance, your best bet is sharding.  This'll give you a much better concurrency and higher disk I/O capacity as you distribute writes across several machines.

Comment: Note that collection-level locking will not help here.

Comment: @Thilo Correct, but it's still useful to note that collection-level locking is on the way. Once it's available, there'll be an extra option of splitting data across multiple collections to reduce lock contention, as well as sharding and distributing across different databases.

Comment: "option of splitting data across multiple collections". How will that work? Is that like a partitioned table in Oracle? i.e. you can still query it as a single collection but it "shards internally"?

Comment: @Thilio I was thinking of something more manual, but I like that idea.  Once collection-level locking is in place, you could build a neat little partitioning layer over multiple collections to reduce locking; it could appear through the driver as a single collection.  Collection-level locking might even be implemented using a lock per extent, rather than per collection, in that case you'd get multiple locks per collection straight out of the box.

Comment: Oh, I see, when you said "there'll be an extra option" you mean an option for the application developer, not a feature of MongoDB, right?

Comment: @Thilio yeah, as in an option to do things differently, not necessarily a new feature

Answer (score 17):

> 2 threads currently do more per sec than 16 threads on a 16 core dual processor machine.

[MongoDB inserts cannot be done concurrently](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+does+concurrency+work#Howdoesconcurrencywork-Operations). Every insert needs to acquire a write lock. Not sure if that is a global or a per-collection lock, but in your case that would not make a difference.

So making this program multi-threaded does not make much sense as soon as Mongo becomes the bottleneck.

> Do I need to use sharding?

You cannot shard a capped collection.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Have you ever heard of capping while at the same time maximizing inserts by using sharding? I know internally it's not a feature for MongoDB, but I wonder if there is a way to cap by using a script or something.

Comment: Maybe MongoDB is not the right solution for high-volume transaction data.

Comment: I think MongoDB has the potential to do high-volume inserts through sharding, but also rotating/capping the database is a challenge.

Comment: there are other constraints other than the lock that can be sped up by multithreading though. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067625/why-does-my-multithreaded-insert-perform-better-than-a-single-threaded-insert

Comment: I believe this answer is correct even for version 3.4.3. The [concurrency documentation] (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/#faq-concurrency) is confusing. It talks about how an insert requires an Intent Exclusive (IX) lock. When you research an intent exclusive lock, this allows you to read in concurrency with a write, but not execute 2 writes in concurrency within a database. To rephrase, attempting to write large amounts of data to the same database (even different collections) with multiple clients seems to slow down the overall throughput. :(

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that building the index after inserting helps.

Comment: You typically do not add indexes to capped collections

Comment: right, I just mentioned it because he was calling ensure_index. So maybe not indexing at all will save even more time?

Comment: What call would I use to not index? I'll probably need indexing though, since these inserts will need to be query-able. Basically, the customer will be logging all their phone calls and need to query those calls based on certain values.

Comment: The use cases for capped collections and queries requiring indexes are usually mutually exclusive. Capped collections are suited for various types of logs and other things that benefit from tailable cursors. As soon as you need queries you're usually better off with a normal collection. Note that you *can* index capped collections, it's just pretty rare for it to make sense.

Comment: @Remon so, it's sounding more and more like I want to use sharding, and then cap the collection outside of mongo using my own app that truncates

Answer (score 2):

uhmm.. you won't get that much performance from one mongodb server.

0.3M * 60 * 60 * 24 = 26G records/day, 180G records/week.
I guess your records size is around 100 bytes, so that's 2.6TB data/day. I don't know what field(s) do you use for indexing but I doubt it's below 10-20 bytes, so just the daily index is going to be over 2G, not to mention the whole week.. the index won't fit into memory, with a lot of queries that's a good recipe for disaster.

You should do *manual* sharding, partitioning the data based on the search field(s). It's a major tel company, you should do replication. Buy a lot of single/dual core machines, you only need cores for the main (perl?) server.

BTW how do you query the data? Could you use a key-value store?

Comment: The system is 12.2TB HD, 192GB RAM and 16 processing cores, so the daily indexing should be ok.

I don't see why I couldn't use a key-value store, if I understand you correctly. What do you have in mind?

Comment: Oh, also, I'll be querying for a result set by a few fields, such as a telephone number, calltime, etc.

Comment: Well, you have to query the data, so if you have complex queries K-V store won't work. If you have simple one-field queries then it might work but for the mentioned multiple fields you have to insert the data (or index) multiple times, further increasing the insert rate.

Comment: @EhevuTov: BTW have you figured out what the bottleneck is? I doubt it's the network, it should be the disk, maaaybe the CPU.

Comment: Something like Redis might work for me.

It's mongod that is the bottleneck. It creates a write-lock for itself and since I can only do about 30k inserts/sec/mongod then I'll need more mongod, which I think I can solve with sharding. I created two mongod instances on separate ports and followed the sharding tutorial, but sharding wasn't working right on my FreeBSD system. The second of the two shards wasn't writing data and only the first was handling and writing data to disk.

Comment: You probably haven't set it up properly. Read the docs about mongodb sharing, it shards based on ranges, so if you use eg the current timestamp as the shard key it will only insert into one of the shards at a time. Note: if you can't tune it the way you want it to work you might want to shard manually, in your app layer. Also note that mongodb=bottleneck is not the final answer, it's still either the CPU or the disk for mongodb that is not fast enough.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but you're asking the same question about hardware, which I have to answer with another question: Why would my old dual core running a slow drive, perform better than a 16 core, RAIDed drive with 192GB RAM? You'd think the 16 core server would perform at least 10 times better. I'm more inline with your thinking that the sharding isn't setup properly and it's something within MongoDB

Comment: I'm saying that a dozen dual core machines with 4G ram and single hard drive could be cheaper and overall provide better performance. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability#Scale_horizontally_.28scale_out.29 You can scale up to some point but then you'll reach a point where no single server on earth would be able to serve the requests and you have to switch to the scale out solution. Many many many companies went on this route. It's better to start with the right architecture right from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you manually cap the collection? You could shard across multiple machines and apply the indexes you need for the queries, and then every hour or so delete the unwanted documents.

The bottleneck you have is most likely the global lock - I have seen this happen in my evaluation of MongoDB for a insert-heavy time-series data application. You need to make sure the shard key is not the timestamp, otherwise all the inserts will execute sequentially on the same machine instead of being distributed across multiple machines.

Answer (score 0):

Write lock on MongoDB is global but quoting [this](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+does+concurrency+work) "collection-level locking coming soon".

> Do I need to use sharding?

Not so easy to answer. If what you can get out of one **mongod** is not meeting your requirements, you kind of have to since sharding is the only way to scale writes on MongoDB (writes on different instances will not block each other).

Comment: You cannot shard a capped collection, though.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I did not see that it was a capped collection.