# Word processing, auto-save MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, caching, architecture

My question is about the structure of the serverside logic of a project I am working on, it basically is a word processor like Google Documents, and it is about the "auto-save" functionality and how it can be effeciently designed, since it is pretty write heavy for a database.

This is how the project's structure is now:

- Users can create documents, a document has multiple pages
- Each page is a different chapter, and the user only edits one page at a time.
- HTML5 contentEditable elements on the page are watched by Javascript and after a decent amount of keypresses, the whole content on the page is submitted to the server "POST //page/" + data of the whole page
- The server uses Node.js and MongoDB to store documents / page content, and saving the page content each x amount of seconds makes it a pretty write heavy operation

We need to optimize the write operation, maybe adding a "write" caching layer on the server (Redis etc?) does anyone has any experience with these kind of architectural decisions?

Comment: In this case I would not necessarily take the term "document" literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, write lock contention would probably be the most important bottleneck since MongoDB has database level lock. Sharding is the correct solution here  ([How to speed up MongoDB Inserts/sec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265176/how-to-speed-up-mongodb-inserts-sec)). It is easy to do with MongoDB, but make sure you optimize everything else before your resort to sharding.

If your current database is going under heavy writes right now, I would recommend you to read [Mailbox's solution to this problem](https://tech.dropbox.com/2013/09/scaling-mongodb-at-mailbox/).

Caching would be hard in this case, because you have to keep invalidating them when other people makes an edit. It will definitely help the read queries, but I reckon the writes will be your biggest bottleneck.

Also, make sure you use a monitor to check the performance. Use some service like MMS to do it for you.