# What's the fastest way to insert a lot of data into MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

We're trying to continuously insert a lot of documents into mongo db, with the mongo db c driver.

Each document has a certain amount of "columns". Each column is a key-value-pair of the document.
Once we've inserted a document we won't modify it, until deletion.

How do we achieve the biggest insert speed (per second) ?

When we tried to insert 5000 Documents each with 200 Columns, in a normal Collection,we got the following results:

- Unacknowledged: It took 0.99s on average (repeated 500 times, variance: 11.03s)
- Acknowledged: It took 3.0s on average, variance 0.97s

If we insert less columns (e.g. only 3 integrers) per document, it's faster: 1s on average to insert 30'000 Documents, unacknowledged.

If we use multiple writers in parallel, the time increases (almost) linearly with the number of writers. We guess that is because of MongoDB's per Database Locks.

Then we tried to use sharding on the local machine. With sharding you can have one writer per shard. We used a hashed sharding key on the _id field. The results were really bad: The insert speed is slower than anything we tried before.

So we got the fastest insert speed when we used exactly one writer and no sharding.

How an we get MongoDB to scale on a single machine?

Can we use capped collections if we want a constantly growing dataset? And will capped collections improve the insertion speed?

Should we use another noSql Database?

The summarized "requirements" for our storage solution:

- We need to be able to continuously insert one-by-one document. We can't use bulk inserts.
- We don't need the data insertion to be acknowledged.
- We wont ever modify the data, only delete it after a certain time.
- We want our storage solution to scale on a single machine.
- If we want to query the data, we look up documents per _id.

Related to: [How to speed up MongoDB Inserts/sec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265176/how-to-speed-up-mongodb-inserts-sec)
This Question is not a duplicate. We have different requirements and use another driver. Maybe we even have a different bottleneck, as the comment's below point out.

Comment: From your description I am pretty sure that not MongoDB, but your disk I/O is the limiting factor.

Comment: Agree with Markus, highly likely that your disk IO is the culprit, though you will want to look at IO stats to be sure. Don't forget that when it gets bad enough an IO bottleneck will cause increased lock percentage, but if you want an immediate comparison, just write to different databases with your threads, thereby increasing the available concurrency - if things are still bad then all the more likely that it is disk contention you are hitting.

Comment: MongoDB is not suitable for writing continuous stream of data, Cassandra seems to be a perfect fit for your use case.